# Python-->sklearn-->preprocessing-->LabelEncoder: Error

Tags: python

I run the codes below to encode and decode labels, while my terminal shows an error:

if diff:DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing as pp
import numpy as np

decode_values=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
encoder=pp.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(decode_values)
print(encoder.inverse_transform(np.array([0,1])))
```

I open the label.py and get the codes leading to the error:

```
def inverse_transform(self, y):
    """Transform labels back to original encoding.

    Parameters
    ----------
    y : numpy array of shape [n_samples]
        Target values.

    Returns
    -------
    y : numpy array of shape [n_samples]
    """
    check_is_fitted(self, 'classes_')

    diff = np.setdiff1d(y, np.arange(len(self.classes_)))

    if diff:
        raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s" % str(diff))
    y = np.asarray(y)
    return self.classes_[y]
```

The variable "diff" in my case should be empty, however the machine fails to understand "if diff". After I change it to "if list(diff)", the error disappeared. I check my textbook and other videos, this error did not happen. I am confused for the difference.

Comment: The `DeprecationWarning` tells you why this is the case. You can't use `if diff` because `diff` will return `False` for now, then will raise an error. "The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous" is self-explanatory. When you used `list(diff)`, this made an empty list, whose truth value is not ambiguous. You should, however, use `if diff.size > 0`, as recommended in the `DeprecationWarning`

Comment: I need learn how to read error message. Thanks!